# Grunt wiredep:app no such file or directory bower.json

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-wiredep

I'm trying to deploy my Yeoman's Angular app to my production server.
When I try to run the grunt build command I get this error:

> Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
>   Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/share/nginx/html/data/gaia-app/app/bower.json' Use --force to continue.

If I use `grunt --force` my app is broken...

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Any ideas?

Comment: I got this message this morning too. But for `grunt serve`. Yesterday it worked without any problems.

Comment: But if grunt won't work it won't build your app as it should.

Comment: Experienced same issue here in OS X Mavericks. After reinstalling OS my project doesn't run `grunt serve` without `--force` anymore (plus got some CSS errors).

Comment: Same problem. I've tried reinstall node and npm and clearing all caches but still the same result.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There are two solutions to this issue depending on which version of wiredep you want to use.

If you want to use '^1.9.0', make sure to remove the cwd property from your Gruntfile.js. This is a common issue if you are an angular-generator user which currently specifies a cwd property on the config for the wiredep task.

If you don't mind using '1.8.0', make sure to pin that version in your package.json. If you are including wiredep via grunt-wiredep, then you will have to add wiredep manually and pin it. In the case that you stick with '1.8.0', leave the cwd property in the config for the task.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to fix.

Comment: Pinning the version to 1.8.0 in Gruntfile worked for me.

Comment: yo angular set wiredep to 1.7.0, upgrading to 1.9.0 and removing the cwd property worked for me, weird thing is that is that another project works fine without changing this.

Comment: @joshs, Which cwd?  the one in imagemin: { dist: { files: [{...  ?

Comment: @joshs Could you explain the "current issue" with specifying a cwd property on the config for the wiredep task? I.e. what is the issue?

Answer (score 28):

Nice after quite some searching on google joshs solution fixed my problem. I just removed `<%= yeoman.app %>`

```
wiredep: {      
  options:  { */code was here */ }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, the latest yeoman angular generator has a few issues I've been troubleshooting all day.

Comment: I removed the whole `options` object from `wiredep` to get rid of the error

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to delete the cwd property from the Grunfile.js

See this for reference:

https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/100

Comment: I just tried this proposed solution and it reports that it is unable to find where it should install bower components.

Answer (score 4):

This answer I found from Melmoth:

[Grunt wiredep:app Cannot find Bower packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182287/grunt-wiredepapp-cannot-find-bower-packages/26186221#26186221)

Plus commenting out line 166 in gruntfile.js :

`// cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'`

fixed the issue for me.

---

**Adding detail as per request**

I am doing the Yeoman 1 hour codelab http://yeoman.io/codelab.html

After installation I ran `grunt serve` and got an error: `Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '../charlottesFolder/app/bower.json'`

I tried moving:

`charlottesFolder/bower.json` to `charlotteFolder/app/bower.json` (don't actually do this as it was wrong)

which then threw the error: `Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages.`

This led me to [Melmoth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182287/grunt-wiredepapp-cannot-find-bower-packages/26186221#26186221) for `Cannot find Bower packages` - his solution worked in conjunction with commenting out the `cwd` line (currently line 166) in `Gruntfile.js`.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail? Thanks.

Comment: Added detail to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for mentioning exact reference 'line 166 in gruntfile.js'

Answer (score -1):

You has to set the grunt-wiredep dependency to the fix version.

"grunt-wiredep": "1.8.0",

Comment: I upgraded grunt-wiredep to 1.8 in my package.json and didn't make any difference. I also tried joshs' solutions (1.9 and no cwd, 1.8 with default yeoman's angular-generator's cwd) and I still get the same warning message.

Comment: wiredep: {
            options: {
//                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
            },

Comment: there's a chance that the 'cwd' is not explicitly comes from your grunt config but came from some other task which ran before the wiredep - I had similar issue, I ran some tests before the wiredep and one of my tests contained a change dir command - check that lead