# Grunt wiredep:app Cannot find Bower packages

Tags: gruntjs

After running

`yo ionic`

from https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic

Then lauching `grunt serve` i've got this :

`Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task` 
`Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages.`

I'm stuck and I can't get a preview of the app.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I update grunt-wiredep 
 `npm install --save-dev grunt-wiredep` 
 and then run a bower install 
`bower install jquery --save`
 I call the Grunt task
 `grunt wiredep`
 and it was done without any errors, finally i could run `grunt serve`

Comment: Didn't help me with generator-webapp unfortunately :(

Comment: Also make sure you actually have the bower packages installed. I just made that mistake. Upgrading to the latest version of wiredep is a good idea too though.

Comment: I've fixed this by upgrading bower from 1.4 to 1.8

Answer (score 1):

@arnaudlrx 's answer is correct but check if you instal git in your machine , because if you run

```
bower install jquery --save
```

but you don't have git installed there nothing will work