# Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman-generator

I'm building an App using **MEAN Stack** and trying to scaffold my frontend using **yeoman-generator**, when I do **yo angular** it fails to build and ends up in the following

```
  Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
  Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I'm stuck with this warning. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182287/grunt-wiredepapp-cannot-find-bower-packages) , but that solution didn't helped me.

Anyhelp will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Node version ????.....

Comment: My node version is v0.10.37

Comment: Pls check after reinstall bower .....

Comment: duplicate of [Grunt wiredep:app Cannot find Bower packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182287/grunt-wiredepapp-cannot-find-bower-packages)

Comment: I tried the steps suggested in that, but no luck :(

Comment: I get this error if my bower_components folder doesn't exist, It can be a permission issue. Try deleting your node_modules,bower_components and do npm install & bower install.. Try them without sudo. if you have .bowerrc file it will specify where to keep bower components

Answer (score 19):

I got the same error on

`grunt serve.`

It was solved when i tried

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli 

npm install -g generator-angular

yo angular

grunt serve
```

if you get an error:-

> Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
>
> Warning: Error: angular is not installed

. Try running `bower install`

Comment: It has worked for me, thanks! (didn't have to run yo angular)

Answer (score 9):

Just run `bower install` and your code will run.

Answer (score 3):

For me it seemed to be link with the rights.
I had to manually create the bower_components folder:

```
mkdir -m 777 client/bower_components
```

and run

```
bower install
```

Answer (score 2):

Put .bowerrc file inside of bower.json file directory.

It must be contain :

```
{
    "directory": "client/bower_components"
}
```

It may be your problem.

Comment: This was my problem, I had set the directory as "bower_components" but it should have been "public/bower_components". I mistakenly thought it was assuming the path to be relative from public but it's relative to the location of your bowerrc.

Answer (score 1):

The Node version seems to be outdated and both the `npm` and `nodejs` is not installed globally:

To install globally run the following:

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli 
npm install -g generator-angular
```

And start again, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the error.

The solution for me was to add the `bower_components` folder on the root folder even if I did not have bower dependencies yet.

Answer (score 0):

For my AngularJS project I had to run this:

```
npm install
npm run bower
```

After that my project ran successfully