# Yeoman with angular-generator error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I'm making my first steps with AngularJS , and I try to create a project using Yeoman. I installed `yeoman`, `bower`, `grunt`, `angular-generator` .
But I get the following error when I use the command `grunt` after using `yo angular myApp` :

> Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task                                                                                    Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

After some researches I found that I should edit my Gruntfile.js file to change the `cwd` parameter, but I couldn't understand how.

`yo doctor` tells me that everything is fine with Yeoman.

I am using Windows 10, I tried to run it in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04, and got the exact same error :(

Tell me if you need more details !

Comment: Can u check where directory is pointed to in .bowerrc file  {
  "directory": "app/components"
}

Comment: { "directory": "bower_components"} is the only line I got in my .bowerrc file. Should I create a bower_components directory at the root of my project ?

Comment: Make sure all the module "dependencies" you defined in bower.json file are at directory pointed by "directory" in .bowerrc

Comment: In my case I have all modules under app/components, so I edited it to { "directory": "app/components" } in .bowerrc file

Comment: Did you try executing `npm install` and `bower install`?

Comment: Yes executing above cmds will install(get) all the required modules under the required directory. Try that first.

Comment: @VincenzoC When running `npm install` I got : npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'A:\Programmation\Angular\test-yeoman\node_modules\bower_components\package.json' 
And when running `bower install` : bower angular-animate#^1.4.0    ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH . 
@Srikanth Should I edit the `"appPath": "app",` line ?

Comment: No need to edit appPath. You should be using either npm or bower to install angular dependencies initailly. Refer to this link https://github.com/angular/bower-angular

Comment: Thanks I'm reading it. Will edit this post when I find the solution. Thank you guys :)

Comment: This link will give you more details.https://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

Comment: please check this [Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578794/error-cannot-find-where-you-keep-your-bower-packages-use-force-to-continue)