# Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. (Ionic Framework)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, bower

I'm stuck.

I tried almost everything. From reinstalling, updating and installing in a different order.

First I used:

```
$ bower install
```

Everything went great so far, but at the end I got this:

```
bower date.format#~1.2.3                ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/tiger-seo/date.format.git", 
exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tiger-seo/date.format.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tiger-seo/date.format.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

I ignored that (don't know if it's necessary) and build the Node Packages with

```
$ npm install
```

and got this:

```
Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The npm-debug.log can you find here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/istqfl11xulkod9/npm-debug.log?dl=0

### My installed versions:

```
Bower: 1.8.0
npm: 3.10.10
node: v6.11.0
Ionic: 3.3.0
Cordova: 7.0.1
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578794/error-cannot-find-where-you-keep-your-bower-packages-use-force-to-continue

Comment: don't work for me, same error