# Grunt serve errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

Im running into issues while using grunt in my terminal. [Here is my Gruntfile.js](http://jsbin.com/pomunubeya/1/)

When I run "grunt serve" in the terminal, here are the errors that I get.

```
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/asdf/Documents/yeoman-test/mytodo/app/bower.json' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-11-14 14:04:11 UTC)
wiredep:app  515ms  
Total 524ms
```

Here is bower.json

```
{
  "name": "mytodo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "~0.13.0",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Comment: Which generator are you using? Are you running the command from this path '/Users/asdf/Documents/yeoman-test/mytodo/`?

Comment: Did you see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709324/grunt-wiredepapp-no-such-file-or-directory-bower-json